# write a recursive function in java that finds and prints the tokens present on the given string use String Tokenizer

Tags: java, recursion

I am sending a `StringTokenizer` object with its length.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer; 
import java.util.Scanner;
class test2
{
    public String display(StringTokenizer st1,String str1,int l)
    {
        int counter  = 0;

        if(st1.nextToken()==' '||st1.equals("."))
            return(str1);
        else
        {
            str1 = st1.nextToken();
            return(display(st1,str1,l));
        }
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Mount Carmel .");
        String str2 = "";
        test2 obj = new test2();
        int l = st.countTokens();
        for(int counter=0;counter<l;counter++)
        {
            str2=obj.display(st,"",l);
            System.out.println(str2);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the output of

```
Mount 
Carmel
```

but the actual output is `incomparable types String and char`

Comment: It's the right output for your program - you have a compilation error in there, where you compare`nextToken()` and `char '  '`. They are indeed incomparable - one is Object type and the other is a primitive.

Comment: step one: stop using StringTokenizer. Do you have any idea how long that has been deprecated? I'm surprised it's even still in the language. Your current problem is here: st1.nextToken()==' '. st1.nextToken() returns a String, '' is a char.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to compare objects use `.equals()` as you you did here `st1.equals(".")`.
Secondly the error is in here `st1.nextToken()==' '`, the error you got tells you that you are comparing two different data types (String which is an object and char which is a primitive type), and you can fix this by `st1.nextToxen().equals(" ")`.
Note that double quotes (" ") are for strings and single quotes (' ') are for chars.
Thirdly classes conventionally starts with capital letters so change every `test2` to `Test2`.

Comment: after correction no syntax error but during run time error is coming java.util.NoSuch ElementException in else part of recursive function

Comment: I have rewritten the code but it's longer that the allowed length of characters so:
https://onlinegdb.com/BkVX4igWB
I hope you understand.